# Bot telegram для отчетов , Запись в файл

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

У меня есть бот в telegram реализованный на python и я хочу научить его запоминать сообщения и записывать их в файл (Именно в файл без использования БД). Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Название функции вывода в файл интересует? Или ищете кто за вас всё напишет?

Comment: Функции , да я и не против чтобы написали. Буду рад любой информации

Answer (score 0):

```
filePath = '/tmp/myFile.txt'
file = open(filePath,'w')

file.write(message1)
file.write(message2)
file.write(message3)

file.close()
```

Comment: `file.close()` забыли? И зачем там `;`?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам!) PS (print для удобства отображения имя пользователя и фамилии

```
 @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
    def msg(message):
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
        print(message.from_user.last_name)
        print(message.from_user.first_name)
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
        file_name = str(message.from_user.last_name) + str(message.from_user.first_name)  + ".txt"
        print(file_name)
        f = open(file_name, 'a')
        f.write(message.text + ' ')
        f.close()
```

Comment: Alex, код лучше прикладывать не картинкой, и можно использовать менеджер `with open(file. 'a') as f:` в таком подходе не нужно `file.close()`

Comment: Благодарю вас за дельный совет

Comment: код в картинках не должен быть